# Saved Credit Cards

Tags: payment, authorize.net, payment-gateway

I'm looking to use saved CC in our EE 1.12 with Auth.net then submitting to 3rd party OMS for capture of Auth.net transaction.  I found Authorize.net CIM integration extensions from Gorilla and Paradox for a pretty penny, also considering Litle or Cybersource ($$).  Anyone have any advice I may not be taking into consideration?

One hurdle we will have is not being able to pass the actual CC info into 3rd party OMS since the 3rd party system isn't setup to use Auth CIM tokens, although Litle, Cybersource tokenization are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you really need to make sure you take into consideration is how you are going to be moving information around between the systems. Make sure that you are transporting the information encrypted and over https.

Doing so any other way may be a violation of PCI Regulations.

Also, because you are using Saved CC, you cannot ask for and store the CVV number. This is absolutely a violation of PCI.

Having said that, what we did to get Auth.net CIM going was using the Saved CC method and then our ERP took all the information and handled the authorization and charging of the card.

One thing you will find is that because Saved CC is not validating the card, you will have orders come to you that will be declined immediately. This is usually because they typed the number in incorrectly or something. You will have to reach out to these customers to get the payment information fixed.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Curious, why did you use Auth.net CIM if you were using the Saved CC anyway?  Maybe I am misunderstanding your process, but isn't the point of the CIM to prevent us from storing the CC's?

Comment: The Magento website used Saved CC to collect the credit card numbers and then those numbers were handed off to the ERP where that used CIM to do the auth and capture of funds. At the time CIM integrations with Magento were non-existent and making our own module was not an option. From what I have seen the CIM integrations in Magento are still pretty weak (though to be fair its been a while since I installed one).

Comment: @JoshPennington, did you sent the data manually or programmatically to your EPR? We are trying to do something similar and I am at a complete loss here. Thanks!

Comment: @Ares - We did it programatically. We wrote a custom API of sorts that facilitates the transferring of the information securely.